# How can I check value returned by rand() with GDB

Tags: debugging, gdb, cross-platform, return-value

So I am debugging my random game in GDB to break how to easily guess numbers.
Line I am referring to in code is:
`winning_number= (rand() % 20) + 1`
After I disassembled the function it looks like this:
[image]

So Underlined in red is an instruction storing the value in EAX register I think.
How can I inspect its value to lookup the number returned by rand() function?
I need (gdb) instruction set.

Answer (score 1):

`rand` in C returns an int in %eax. You can view its value in GDB with the command `print $eax`. See the [Examining Data](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Data.html) section of the GDB manual.

The value will only be valid after the call to `rand` has completed and before the `mov $0x66666667,%eax` instruction has been executed, so you may want to either single-step the program by using the `stepi` or `nexti` commands, or set a breakpoint at the address `*0x08049019`.

> Underlined in red is an instruction storing the value in EAX register I think

`mov %eax,%ecx` copies the value that is held in %eax to %ecx.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got this solved:

This is how I broke it down.
I found out that the whole instruction `winning_number=(rand() %20) + 1` is disassembled to this:
[image]

in the bottom line there is an output ready in EAX register and it is moved to address of winning_number value (underlined in red). Following the suggestion I added a breakpoint at address *0x804903b and here we go.